# How to fix all tables when move from MDPI latex to ELSEVIER's

Tags: tables, overleaf, mdpi

I built my tables based on MDPI latex template

Now we are considering Elsevier format

but when I moved the tables to the new template they all got missed up

Here is how they looks like now
[image]

while before in MDPI they looked like this

[image]

[image]

Here is the script I used

```
\begin{table*}
\caption{Dataset after NLP process.}
\label{table_FinalDataset}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cCCCCCccccc}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Report ID}}
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Features}}
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{ICDs}} \\ 
\cline{2-11}
& \textbf{C0004482} & \textbf{C0224473} & \textbf{C0719349}
& \textbf{C0230431} & \textbf{C0420607} & \textbf{295}
& \textbf{300}  & \textbf{303}  & \textbf{540}
& \textbf{560}\\
\midrule
            1012    &6  &0  &0  &4  &2  &0  &1  &1  &0  &0\\            
            1013    &0  &2  &2  &8  &0  &1  &1  &0  &0  &1  \\          
            1014    &0  &0  &4  &4  &9  &1  &0  &1  &0  &0  \\ 
            
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}




\begin{table*}
\caption{Diagnoses Binary Array.}
\label{table_BinaryArray}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{CCCCCCCCCCC}
\toprule
            \textbf{\thead{Diagnosis}}
            &\textbf{\thead{Rep 1}}
            &\textbf{\thead{Rep 2}}
            &\textbf{\thead{Rep 3}}
            &\textbf{\thead{Rep 4}}
            &\textbf{\thead{Rep 5}}
            &\textbf{\thead{Rep 6}}
            &\textbf{\thead{Rep 7}}
            &\textbf{\thead{Rep 8}}
            &\textbf{\thead{Rep 9}}\\
   
\midrule
            295 &1  &1  &0  &0  &0  &0  &1  &1  &0\\            
            303 &0  &1  &0  &0  &0  &1  &0  &1  &0\\            
            560 &0  &0  &1  &1  &0  &1  &0  &1  &1\\                                    
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
```

How to fix that with minimum effort

I have 10 tables

here is the template I used

https://www.overleaf.com/project/new/template/29119?id=28568212&latexEngine=pdflatex&mainFile=cas-dc-template.tex&templateName=Elsevier%E2%80%99s+CAS+LaTeX+Double-Column+Template&texImage=texlive-full%3A2022.1

Comment: Please state which document class you employ.

Comment: i would guess you are using `tabularx` syntax without loading the `tabularx` package,